# Async method not reporting back correctly from list of tasks

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

I have four tasks to run within the MainViewModel of a C# WPF Windows Application. All the tasks call the same Update method, using a different parameter value for each execution. I call the Update method in the MainViewModel like this:

```
//UpdateStatus is another method in the MainViewModel (see below)
var progress = new Progress<string>(data => UpdateStatus(data));
var tasks = new List<Task>();

//There are some DataTables that I have summarised here to have names that start with "dt_" as seen below
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => FileSchema_Tradacom_tab = FileSchema.Update_FileSchema(dt_T, FileStyle.Tradacom, progress)));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => FileSchema_Edifact_tab = FileSchema.Update_FileSchema(dt_E, FileStyle.EdiFact, progress)));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => FileSchema_DepotList_tab = FileSchema.Update_FileSchemac(dt_D, FileStyle.DepotList, progress)));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => FileSchema_ProductList_tab = FileSchema.Update_FileSchema(dt_P, FileStyle.ProductList, progress)));

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

[... code continues...]
```

Inside the method, the `FileStyle` parameter is used to report back the status for that execution.

```
public static DataTable Update_FileSchema(DataTable dt, FileStyle fileStyle,IProgress<string> progress)
{
    progress.Report($"1[{StatusCode.Connecting}]Connecting...");

    [...Code to retrieve data from csv files and SQL queries...]

    //note the use of the fileStyle parameter to add detail
    progress.Report($"0[{StatusCode.Connected}]File Schema ({fileStyle}) Retrieved");
}
```

finally, the method that Updates the Status Pane on my application window looks like this is also in the MainViewModel

```
private void UpdateStatus(string message)
{
    //Sets the values of various properties of the MainViewModel, including Status and StatusMessage,
    //Which are displayed in a WPF TextBlock
    if (message.Contains("]"))
    {
        try
        {
            this.Status = this.Status ?? "";
            //The message comes after the bit in square brackets
            var newMessage = $"{(Status.Length == 0? "":"\n")}{message.Substring(message.IndexOf("]") + 1)}";
            //The new line indicator (1 or 0) comes before the square brackets
            var addLine = message.Substring(0, message.IndexOf("[")) == "1";
            //The code is the bit inside the square brackets (gotta get the start and end points of this one)
            var codeFrom = message.IndexOf("[") + 1;
            var codeTo = message.LastIndexOf("]");
            var codeValue = message.Substring(codeFrom, codeTo - codeFrom);
            this.StatusCode = (StatusCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(StatusCode), codeValue);

            [...More code that goes on to update other properties of this MainViewModel...]
}
```

I had hoped when running this to see four identifiably different reports in the application status window, reporting each of the four tasks. Instead, although I get four reports but they all say the same thing - I see "File Schema (DepotList)" repeated four times.

If I add a `Thread.Sleep(10000);` between the two reports in the Update method, I see that each of the statuses is updating correct line in the Status Pane Textblock in that when it is not adding a new line, it replaces the correct "Connecting..." line that was inserted earlier in the method execution.

I don't understand why the reporter is not taking the different values of the fileStyle parameter and spitting them back out in the progress report; surely each concurrent execution of the method runs separately with separate values in the parameter? In fact I see that this is the case when I run a SQL Profiler, I see four separate queries being made each with a different fileStyle! Any pointers would be extremely welcome.

Comment: Try to create an [**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and post it. How are your backend methods wired to the XAML? Where the methods(the one with tasks) being called.

Comment: I made a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example and... Didn't see the problem. I have narrowed the problem down to the behaviour of the UpdateStatus method... where it is being called asynchronously, it seems to be replacing out the wrong lines of the status. I think the best solution will be to implement @Theodore's suggestion and work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but you could benefit by passing structured data through the `Progress`, instead of passing strings that later have to be laboriously parsed. [`ValueTuple`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples)s are excellent for this job:

```
var progress = new Progress<(StatusCode, string)>(data => UpdateStatus(data));
```

```
public static DataTable Update_FileSchema(DataTable dt, FileStyle fileStyle,
    IProgress<(StatusCode, string)> progress)
{
    progress.Report((StatusCode.Connecting, $"Connecting..."));
    //...
    progress.Report((StatusCode.Connected, $"File Schema ({fileStyle}) Retrieved"));
}
```

```
private void UpdateStatus((StatusCode, string) progressData)
{
    var (statusCode, message) = progressData;
    //...
}
```

Another thing that looks suspicious is assigning the `FileSchema_Tradacom_tab` etc properties from the background thread. My assumption is that these properties are tied with UI elements. If that's the case, you should do the assignments on the UI thread. Here is one way to do it:

```
var factories = new List<Func<Task>>();
factories.Add(async () => FileSchema_Tradacom_tab = await Task.Run(
    () => FileSchema.Update_FileSchema(dt_T, FileStyle.Tradacom, progress)));
factories.Add(async () => FileSchema_Edifact_tab = await Task.Run(
    () => FileSchema.Update_FileSchema(dt_E, FileStyle.EdiFact, progress)));
factories.Add(async () => FileSchema_DepotList_tab = await Task.Run(
    () => FileSchema.Update_FileSchemac(dt_D, FileStyle.DepotList, progress)));
factories.Add(async () => FileSchema_ProductList_tab = await Task.Run(
    () => FileSchema.Update_FileSchema(dt_P, FileStyle.ProductList, progress)));
Task[] tasks = factories.Select(f => f()).ToArray();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: The Progress change is valuable for sure. The Factories change I need to understand better, but I will take the advice and try to implement it. This is my first implementation of any complexity of async operation and although I have tried to learn, the first practical is always a challenge!

Comment: @HighPlainsGrifter yeah, dealing with factories (asynchronous delegates) can certainly be a bit daunting, especially if you are not familiar with the concept. You could take a look at the [1st revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65846742/1) of this answer for a more familiar approach.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because it was the most useful to me in solving the problem, although part of the problem was caused by another aspect of my code, which was based on a deeper misunderstanding of asynchronous behaviour (not being aware of concatenated string values at any moment). However, using the array of tasks and `List<Func<Task>>` was the solving grace.

Comment: Thanks @HighPlainsGrifter for accepting this answer. Being *the most* useful is flattering, until I realized that this was *the only* answer that this question received. 

Comment: oh man, I didn't realise that until you mentioned - lots of high quality comments!